# Convert ZIP code to lat long

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, geocoding

I have a situation where user input is ZIP code and google map should be plotted with stores in that ZIP.
Do anyone know how to convert ZIP code to lat long using `Geocoding' or other technique?

Comment: Maybe an answer here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Also this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461803/geolocating-an-ip-address